# При сборке jar пропадает background и иконки

Tags: java, maven, jar

Видел несколько ответов, но они не понятны. У меня программа в IDEA выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а в jar, собранный Maven (build artifacts), так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так гружу иконки:

```
btn_add_to_list.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\\icons\\create.png"));
btn_del_from_list.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\\icons\\delete.png"));
```

так background:

```
static class Bground extends JPanel{
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            Image im = null;
            try {
                im = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\background.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }

setContentPane(new Bground());
```

Пишут везде, что надо как-то этот путь заменить, что jar их не видит, т.к. они внешние.. а как сделать чтобы увидел, что и где прописать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="activation-1.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="jxl-2.6" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: `maven` имеет свою  структуру папок и все что находится вне папок `src/main/java` и `src/main/resources` просто игнорируется без специальных настроек. Все ваши картинки не попадают в сборку. Нужно переместить все картинки в папку `resources`. И писать путь не от `src`, а от корня `jar` файла. К примеру: `icons/create.png`.

Comment: Выше вставил картинку с содержимым jar.. где здесь такие папки? во всех подкаталогах тоже нет.. может моя IDEA не до конца настроена?

Comment: Во-первых, с упаковываемыми в jar файлами нужно работать как с ресурсами. Во-вторых, ресурсы не должны лежать в каталоге src.

Comment: Что делать то? Ваши ответы вызывают много вопросов

Comment: @mrprogre нужно учить `maven`, его структуру и как с ним работать и как работать с ресурсами.

Comment: @mrprogre покажите лучше структуру проекта, а не `jar` файла.

Comment: Выше указал, оно? Я просто не знал, что чтобы собрать проект целиком, недостаточно просто написать программу, надо учить Maven оказывается..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ уже написан в комментариях, но продублирую, потому что сказали, что не совсем поняли. Выделяю основную часть из текста.

Нужно **переместить все картинки в папку resources**. И писать путь не от src, а от корня jar файла. К примеру: icons/create.png.

Answer (score 0):

Надо было создать папку **res** или **resources**.
Вот так надо делать для кнопок:

```
btn_del_from_list.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(getClass().getResource("res/icons/delete.png"))));
```

так, для картинок:

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("res/background.jpg"));
```